# Matlab: modifying one field of defined structure in other used function

Tags: matlab, data-structures, datafield

I have defined a data structure `data` with 7 fields. Two of the fields is as:

```
n = 4;
data = struct();
data.Aeq = zeros(n);
data.beq = zeros(n,1);
m =3;
```

Now, there is another function `ul(data,m)` that I am passing the `data` and `m` as inputs. Inside `ul()`, I will modify one component of matrix `Aeq` as:

```
data.Aeq(m,m) = 1;
```

after running whole the code when I am checking `data.Aeq` it is still zero matrix while I have modified on component. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables modifed within a function do not change outside of the function. You should return data as the output of function ul. For example:

```
function data=ul(data,m)
data.Aeq(m,m) = 1
end

n = 4;
data = struct();
data.Aeq = zeros(n);
data.beq = zeros(n,1);
m =3;

data = ul(data,m)
```

data.Aeq should now be modified correctly.